# Cool URI returns 404 if the same name PHP exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using a cool uri in `.htaccess` something like that:

`RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z-]*)/$ /view.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]`

The problem is, when I use URL that matches existing filename in root, it returns 404 error.

For instance I want a cool URI `/eshop/` that will call `/view.php?m=eshop` but it doesn't work, if there's a file `/eshop.php` in root.

If a change it to `/eshop-test/` everything is OK.

How can I make it works? Is there any PHP setting needed?

Comment: I think the problem is being caused by **Multiviews** . Try disabling it . Put this line at the top of your htaccess  `Options -Multiviews`